# Library Handles in node-ffi

Tags: c, node.js, gssapi, node-ffi

I'm playing with integrating the gssapi into node.js. Im not sure how to represent this:

The `gss_init_sec_context` function contains many struct based parameters, some of which are nested pretty deeply. For example this struct:

```
typedef struct gss_ctx_id_struct
{
  gss_OID mech;
#ifdef USE_KERBEROS5
  struct _gss_krb5_ctx_struct *krb5;
#endif
} gss_ctx_id_desc;
```

So based on this I'm guessing I need to implement some kind of Structure (with ref-struct) to represent the `krb5` pointer (since kerberos5 is being used).  So I looked at this `_gss_krb_ctx_struct` and saw this...

```
 typedef struct _gss_krb5_ctx_struct {
   Shishi *sh;
   Shishi_ap *ap;
   Shishi_tkt *tkt;
   Shishi_key *key;
   gss_name_t peerptr;
   int acceptor;
   uint32_t acceptseqnr;
   uint32_t initseqnr;
   OM_uint32 flags;
   int reqdone;
   int repdone;
 } _gss_krb5_ctx_desc, *_gss_krb5_ctx_t;
```

Where Shishi is a pointer to a library, and shishi_ap appears to be a pointer to a function. I'm not sure how to implement these things in node-ffi.  Can someone give me some guidance here?

Comment: I will just say that when I did a Kerberos integration project, I studied GSSAPI and ended up using SASL (which underneath can use GSSAPI on your behalf).  So if you get stuck with GSSAPI, consider SASL as an easier-to-use alternative.